# Cocoa leaves turning brown

Tags: trees, plant-health, plant-care, leaves, tropical

[image]

Hello,
My 4 months old cocoa plants are starting to get brown.
Any idea what is the reason? Is this the cold weather? to much watering?
What should I do?
And does the left one still have a chance to survive?